# Migrating values with in usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have two user controls named

1. Welcome
2. Data

in one main window

In the second usercontrol I'm using a datagrid. On change of the elements in the datagrid I must be able to set the value in the `Welcome` user control

In the `Welcome` user control

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Name:" FontWeight="Bold" Name="lblClientName" />
    <TextBox Name="txtClientName" Width="85" 
      Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the `Data` user control

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here on change of this event i must be able to display 
    // data in textbox i.e.txtClientName
}
```

Comment: you can create a custom event in Data user control. and subscribe to its event where welcome user control need some action on it.

Comment: On every row click in the datagrid the value of the textbox(in the welcome user control) has to change, I m confused with this please can any one provide me sample code

Answer (score 0):

This is something very simple just need some basic knowledge of .net framework.. i hope this could help you. i have just created a custom event in Data usercontrol that will bubble the row event.

Data UserControl Code:

```
 public partial class Data : UserControl
    {

        private event EventHandler _RowSelectionChanged;
        public event EventHandler RowSelectionChanged
        {
            add { _RowSelectionChanged += value; }
            remove { _RowSelectionChanged -= value; }
        }

        private void RaiseSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_RowSelectionChanged != null)
                _RowSelectionChanged(sender, e);
        }
        public Data()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseSelectionChanged(sender, e);
        }

    }
```

Welcome UserControl Code:

```
 public partial class Welcome : UserControl
    {
        public Welcome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string ClientName
        {
            get 
            {
                return txtClientName.Text;
            }
            set
            {

                txtClientName.Text = value;

            }
        }
    }
```

Main Window Class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ucData.RowSelectionChanged += new EventHandler(ucData_RowSelectionChanged);
        }

        void ucData_RowSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ev = e as SelectionChangedEventArgs;
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            ucWelcome.ClientName = "any thing";
            //this is how you can change Welcome UserControl
        }
    }
```

Regards.